# Ошибка при инициализации фрагмента

Tags: android-viewpager, android, android-fragment

В проекте используется viewpager, внутри которого fragment. При создании viewpager с одной страницей проект работает нормально, но когда страниц больше одной приложение крашится. Вот код создания фрагмента:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.image1);
        img.setImageResource(imgs[0]);          
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Ошибка вылетает на этой строке, когда уже пытается создать второй раз фрагмент:

> View rootView =
> inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
>                   container, false);

Вот xml файл

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:src="@drawable/foto2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

И сам лог ошибок

```
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at com.example.padmenu.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:237)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:160)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:895)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:772)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1234)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1017)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1017)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2163)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1091)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930):    ... 52 more
12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930): Caused by: java.lang.OutO
```

Comment: Это может быть из-за того, что я туда здоровые картинки кидаю? порядка 2-4 мб, jpeg

Comment: Да запросто. 2-4 мегабайтный jpeg при распаковке легко может занимать в памяти 15-20 мегабайт.

Comment: + viewpager  не освобождает память, ondestroy у фрагментов вызывается

Comment: Проблема была в размерах изображений, сделал их меньше размером, но разрешением в районе ~1000-700, но теперь приложение тормозит. Есть ли способ оптимизации декодирования изображений?

Comment: Попробуйте кэшировать изображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `12-17 14:56:14.772: E/AndroidRuntime(31930): Caused by: java.lang.OutO`

Судя по всему, в процессе создания фрагмента (в `onCreateView`) возникает `OutOfMemoryError`.